# Fancybox2 - dragging scrollbar closes the modal

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I used `data-fancybox=""` to open fancybox2 iframe (without any extra script). When I scroll the page by dragging the scrollbar, the modal is closed on mouse release (It acts like clicking outside of modal). However scrolling using the mouse wheel works fine. I used fancybox like this:

```
<a href="email.php" data-fancybox="">Send Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by moving from fancybox2 to fancybox3 however `data-type` is mandatory in fancybox3 and is not `iframe` by default.